# How to add buttons starting from a specific cell with VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that creates several delete Buttons accordingly to my table size, but the issue is my table doesnt start in the second row and if i change it to start from the right cell it wont create all the buttons. Wat changes i do need in code to make it start from the cell i need?

```
Sub AddButtonDelete()

  Dim EnterLine As Integer, cell As Range, button As Object
  
  

  For EnterLine = 2 To Range("Data").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count ' Data is the table name
 
    Set cell = Range("n" & EnterLine)
    cell.Value = "button" & EnterLine
    Set button = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(cell.Left, cell.Top, cell.Width, cell.Height)
    
    With button
       .Caption = "Delete"
       .Name = "Button" & EnterLine
       .OnAction = "Delete"
    End With
    
   Next EnterLine
   
End Sub
```

Thats the result im getting now:
[image: Thats what im getting now]

And thats the result i was expecting:
[image]

Comment: It's not really clear to me what's your problem. Anyway: have you tried to change the `EnterLine` starting value to 1 and then setting cell to `Range("n" & EnterLine + 1)`?

Comment: yes, thats the Solution, i cant believe i missed such a trivial detail. just to clarify i found this code from a website and edited it but im still on my way to learn VBA. Thanks for ur time! thats exactly wat i was missing haha